# How do you calculate the Expectation $E(X^4)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

Suppose $X$ is a normal random variable with, $\mu_x\ {\ne}\ 0\ \text{or}\ 1$ and $\sigma_x\ {\ne}\ 0\ \text{or}\ 1$. I would like to show that the expectation $E(X^4)$ has the following equality: $E(X^4)\ {=}\ \mu_x^4+6\sigma_x^2\mu_x^2+3\sigma_x^4$.

I tried to prove this by calculating $E[(x-\mu_x)^4]$ which leads me to

$E[(x-\mu_x)^4]\ {=}\ E(x^4-4x^3\mu_x+6x^2\mu_x^2-4x\mu_x^3+\mu_x^4)$

$E(x^4)\ {=}\ 4\mu_xE(x^3)-6\mu_x^2\sigma_x^2-3\mu_x^4+E[(x-\mu_x)^4]$

where I used $E(x^2)\ {=}\ \sigma_x^2+\mu_x^2$ and $E(x)\ {=}\ \mu_x$ to combine terms. This result didn't seem to help. I've looked into using the generating function approach but for $\mu_x\ {\ne}\ 0\ \text{or}\ 1$ and $\sigma_x\ {\ne}\ 0\ \text{or}\ 1$ these calculations become tedious very quickly. Is there an easy and quick way to show this?

Comment: Hint: write the integral for $E(X^3)$ and notice something... magical.

Comment: A helpful lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_lemma

Comment: Hint: write $X=\mu+\sigma Z$ with $Z\sim N(0,\,1)$, then expand $E(X^4)$ in terms of $E(Z^n)$ with $n\le4$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\mu+\sigma Z$ where $Z$ is the standard normal random variable.

If you write the integral for $E(Z^n)$   and integrate by parts you obtain the simple relationship $$E(Z^{n+2})=(n+1)E(Z^n).$$

Therefore $E(Z^4)=3$. Then
$$E(X^4)=E(\mu ^4+4\sigma \mu ^3Z+6\sigma ^2 \mu ^2Z^2+4\sigma ^3\mu Z^3+ \sigma ^4Z^4
)=\mu ^4+6\sigma ^2 \mu ^2+3 \sigma ^4.$$